# Pass Event to Function

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a class that has a lot of events, but these events have the exact same signature. After each raised event i have to process the result written back to the event args, also the same for each event. These events are like the same but they have a different semantic meaning, so i would like to have them as seperate events rather than one event with a property, where the consumer would have to check inside the handler if it is the right event (I would find this ugly).

So currently my code is like that:

```vb
Public Class MyEventArgs
    Inherits EventArgs

    Public Property InputData As Object
    Public Property OutputData As Object
End Class

Public Delegate Sub MyEventDelegate(sender As Object, e As MyEventArgs)

Public Event EventOne As MyEventDelegate

Private Sub OnEventOne(inputData As Object)
    Dim e = New MyEventArgs With {.InputData = inputData}
    RaiseEvent EventOne(Me, e)
    ' Process e.OutputData
End Sub
```

' ... And so on, and so on, with EventTwo/OnEventTwo and a dozen more events that are exactly the same (apart from the name of the event)

I tried the following two codes, but none work:

```vb
Private Sub OnEvent(ev as Event, inputData As Object)
    Dim e = New MyEventArgs With {.InputData = inputData}
    RaiseEvent ev(Me, e)
    ' Process e.OutputData
End Sub
```

This does not work because Event is not a Type. Also I tried

```vb
Private Sub OnEvent(ev as MyEventDelegate, inputData As Object)
    Dim e = New MyEventArgs With {.InputData = inputData}
    ev(Me, e)
    ' Process e.OutputData
End Sub
```

But then I can't pass the Event as parameter

What can I do to get it to work ?

Comment: I'm slightly confused. Isn't what you're complaining about actually what Microsoft do with eg Mouse events (multiple events, different names, all have a MouseEvntArgs) or key events (multiple events keydown/keyup that have KeyEventArgs)?

Comment: Why do you have the OnXxx methods at all? Surely it's reasonably compact to just declare 12 events at the top of the class and then use RaiseEvent them during your processing?

Comment: @CaiusJard I need to instanciate the event =args and evaluate the result after the event. If I don't have a function for this i would have to multiply this piece of code even more to all places where I raise these events

Comment: @PeterDuniho I am not aware of a difference between c# and vb.net regarding events. Could you point me to any ?

Comment: Mmm, keyword spamming to increase the visibility of your question might not go down well. We've got some awesome experts that check vb.net too (I'm mainly a c# guy but you're right; I can't tell the difference between the two languages and never understand why some people get so bent out of shape being pointed to a c# answer to their vb question ... anyhoos). So I think I understand that you're trying to get away with not writing 12 methods called OnXxx1 thru OnXxx12, you just want to write one and then call OnXxx and pass the event to raise. There are tricks that could do this but...

Comment: ...you need to remember that OnXxx aren't for YOU, they're for the next guy who decides to subclass your class and wants to raise your events. And asking him to raise them by calling your single OnXxx and passing some indicator as to which event to raise is weird/nonstandard/not going to make his day any better. If you don't plan on allowing subclasses to raise, just omit the OnXxx and have 12 events that you raiseevent at various points in your code

Comment: @CaiusJard well, that is a good point, I intended this function for me. Probably no one will ever inherit it. It is for a internal framework, where other might reuse the control, but probably not descend from it

Comment: @EricPitz Is there an `AddHandler` to associate the event with the handler?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Not quite sure about your question. There will be `AddHandler` in the consumer's code, but not in mine

Comment: _"I am not aware of a difference between c# and vb.net regarding events. Could you point me to any?"_ -- once you've read the language documentation for that feature in each language, you can easily see the difference. One clear and fundamental difference is that VB.NET distinguishes between raising an event and invoking other types of delegates. VB.NET also has syntax for declaring methods as event handlers directly, rather than simply adding a delegate to an event.

Comment: I would consider twice to depend on the fact that event handlers need to update some of the provided arguments. Why not use a method with return value instead? While there are cases where such approach has been used (Winforms FormClosing or BackgroundWorker events) - events designed to inform other parts about something without knowing of other parts existence. When I don't know about their existence, I don't care what they do

Comment: @Fabio The OutputData are in fact multiple Properties, like Color, Font, FontSize, ... that the consumer can customize. If he does'nt set them, a default will be used

Comment: @Fabio it's not entirely unreasonable, I think, to have a paradigm where an app says to anyone who is listening "I'm about to do this, and it's your last chance to change my behavior before I do it". Perhaps the only complication that arises is when multiple event handlers are listening it isn't clearly defined which one will win(run last), in the case that they all do different things to the same properties of the "output" object. In the first proposal I make below this is reasonably avoided by the fact that there can be only one operative delegate for a particular "event"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events aren't first class things and cannot be passed around like you imagine. They're actually something more like a collection of delegates and the AddHandler/RaiseEvent keywords just put delegates into the collection/call them if they aren't null.

Conceptually, when you write:

```
Public Event X(EventArgs)
```

The compiler turns it into something like:

```
Delegate Sub XDeleg(e As EventArgs)
Private d as New List(Of XDeleg)
```

And when you write:

```
MyMethod(e as EventArgs) handles someObj.X
```

The compiler creates:

```
d.Add(AddressOf MyMethod)
```

And when you do:

```
RaiseEvent X(someArgs)
```

The compiler creates:

```
For Each dDeleg in d
    dDeleg(someArgs)
Next d
```

As such you can hopefully appreciate that Events are a *concept* rather than a *thing* that can be passed around like a variable

I think, short of using reflection, you probably want to replicate something like it yourself, but (unless you plan to support multiple event hooks) have only a single delegate per interesting thing(formerly referred to as Event), to which some external method can be attached. This method will do the work in response to something happening in your class, like an event would. I make the recommendation that you have only a single delegate because you are specifically looking for your external method to alter something that is fed back to your class. If you attach multiple delegates to the same thing you then have the headsache of controlling the order that they run in

When we have a bunch of variables that we want to address programmatically we usually put them in some collection. I'm thus proposing to just have a collection of delegate and some named properties that expose them, this way internally you can access the delegate by an array position, but externally the class has delegate properties you can have the external entities connect methods to:

```vb
Public Class MyEventArgs

    Public Property InputData As Object

    Public Property OutputData As Object
End Class

Public Class X

    Public Delegate Sub MyEventDelegate(sender As Object, e As MyEventArgs)

    Private d(11) as MyEventDelegate

    Public Property EventOne As MyEventDelegate
        Get
            Return d(0)
        End Get

        Set
            d(0) = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property EventTwo As MyEventDelegate
        Get
            Return d(1)
        End Get

        Set
            d(1) = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub DoWork()
        'blah
        OnEvent("hello", 1)
    End Sub

    Private Sub OnEvent(inputData As Object, whichDeleg as Integer)
        If d(whichDeleg) Is Nothing Then Return
        Dim e = New MyEventArgs With {.InputData = inputData}
        d(whichDeleg)(Me, e)
    ' Process e.OutputData
    End Sub
End Class
```

If you really want events you might consider it simpler to

```
Public Class MyEventArgs

    Public Property InputData As Object

    Public Property OutputData As Object
End Class

Public Class X

    Public Event EventOne(MyEventArgs)

    Public Event EventTwo(MyEventArgs)

    Private Sub DoWork()
        'blah
        OnEvent("hello", 1)
    End Sub

    Private Sub OnEvent(inputData As Object, whichDeleg as Integer)
        Dim e = New MyEventArgs With {.InputData = inputData}
        Select whichDeleg
            Case 1
                RaiseEvent EventOne(e)
            Case 2
                RaiseEvent EventTwo(e)
        End Select
    ' Process e.OutputData
    End Sub
End Class
```

A Select statement is going to be a lot more compact than repeating the entire method over and over

But (and it's a big but) you should be aware that leveraging events means each event can have multiple handling methods and if they do different things it isn't clear cut which one will be called last. Unlike the first scenario where we had control over the number of instances of delegates, this is more like implementing a collection (events 1 - 12) of a collection (N handlers of any one event) of delegates. Take care with it!

Comment: Thank you. I had a rough understanding of the principle, I had hoped there would have been a work around, or some "hack". Unluckily it seems not. Reflection is probably not the best way to go either. As my goal is to merely shorten the code, your first solution will probably not be shorter, as I will have to declare lots of properties, but the Select statement is not to bad. I think I will go for that way